# How create my jquery ui custom dialog?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

Hi I need to create this design from jquery ui dialog and I do not know where to start

I have several problems because it takes the jquery libraries ui and I do not manage to reach my goal

This is the template:

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L72SV.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could start from here: http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/
This way you could at least customize the coloring of the dialog.

Then you need to download your custom css and create the dialog based on the components you need (form elements and the actual dialog).